# Limpar histórico do bash no Kali Linux

Tags: bash, histórico

As pesquisas que eu fiz sobre limpar o histórico do bash foram inúteis. Eu usei `history -c`, mas o terminal não aceitou uma opção `-c`, nem `-w`. Eu tentei apagar o arquivo /.bash_history, mas não existe o arquivo /home/usuario/.bash_history. O Bleachbit também não trabalhou nesse sentido.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O kali linux usa ZSH como terminal. Tente ver se há um desses arquivos para limpá-los ou editá-los:

```
$HOME/.zsh_history
$HOME/.zhistory
```